# How to make a checkbox have checked be non null and unchecked be null

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have a date column that i've turned into a checkbox. How do I make it so when the date isn't null the checkbox is checked and if it is null then make it unchecked?

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather keep my `DATE` column *as is*, but make it **hidden**. Create another - checkbox item - and create (two?) trigger(s):

- `POST-QUERY` (which fires when you query existing data)
- `WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM` (which fires when you modify data on the screen)

  - if you keep the date column hidden, maybe you don't need it. Or, you do if that date column is modified by some process

Trigger code is simple (presuming that `0` means "not checked" and `1` means "checked"):

```
:block.checkbox_item := case when :block.date_column is null then 0
                             else 1
                        end;
```

If your Forms version doesn't *speak* `CASE`, use `DECODE` instead (it requires the `SELECT` statement):

```
select decode(:block.date_column, null, 0, 1)
  into :block.checkbox_item
  from dual;
```

Comment: That worked wonderfully. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Since it's a checkbox, the When-Validate-Item trigger could be a When-Checkbox-Changed trigger, instead.

Comment: @Andy, it is not supposed to fire when checkbox itself is changed as its state depends on the date item. So - no, I don't think that it should be changed. Thank you for the comment, though.

Comment: @Littlefoot, I misunderstood the question a bit, I guess.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: No problem, @Andy :)